# Converting an XML into a PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, xml

I have the following array set in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hats>
    <a id="Chicago BULLS" img="bulls.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
    <b id="Toronto RAPTORS" img="raptors.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
    <c id="Orlando MAGIC" img="magic.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
</hats>
<clothes>
    <a id="Chicago BULLS 23" img="bullstee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
    <b id="Toronto RAPTORS 23" img="torontotee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
    <c id="Orlando MAGIC 23" img="magictee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
</clothes>
```

I have used a function I found to convert the XML into a Multidimensional Array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [hats] => Array
        (
            [a] => Array
                (
                )

            [a_attr] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Chicago BULLS
                    [img] => bulls.jpeg
                    [cost] => $25.00
                )

            [b] => Array
                (
                )

            [b_attr] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Toronto RAPTORS
                    [img] => raptors.jpeg
                    [cost] => $25.00
                )

            [c] => Array
                (
                )

            [c_attr] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Orlando MAGIC
                    [img] => magic.jpeg
                    [cost] => $25.00
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see it has only taken half of the XML file, and also I am unable to use numbers so have to resort to letters.

Ultimately I am trying to have it read the XML file then output only what is shown within the  tags and  tags and eventually more.

How can I parse the XML file cleanly into an array so I can then use a foreach loop to show each line in a given section of the XML file (hats only or clothes only).

Comment: @NathanSrivi I don't have the php written up yet but it will be something like:
foreach $array->hats $out (
echo $out['id'] )
With more HTML formatting to show each item individually in its own <div> 
Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why not read directly from XML with `simplexml`?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->children() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: <br />"; // name of the node, e.g. '<hats>'
    foreach ($value->children() as $item) {
        echo "$item[id], $item[img], $item[cost]<br />";
    }
}
```

see this working: http://3v4l.org/dpjsg

In case you are the creator of this XML, make it easier to parse like this:

```
<items>
    <group name="hats">
        <item id="1" name="Chicago BULLS" img="bulls.jpeg" cost="25.00" />
    </group>
    <group name="clothes">
        ...
    </group>
</items>
```

Comment: This is definitely a good approach, but your access for attributes really should quote the strings, not rely on bare words (undefined constants): `$item['id']` not `$item[id]`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where exactly you're going with the "easier to parse" example - you seem to have exchanged specifically named elements for calling everything `group`...

Comment: The tags 'hats' and 'clothes' will only be used as separators for the inside elements, these main elements will not contain values or be directly referenced.

Comment: @IMSoP easier to parse: (1) separating structure (=group) from content (=hats), (2) e.g. selecting all items with xpath is easier when items are `<items>` and not `<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>`, `<d>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xml_parse_into_struct` — Parse XML data into an array structure

Syntax: **int xml_parse_into_struct ( resource $parser , string $data , array &$values [, array &$index ] )**
This function parses an XML string into 2 parallel array structures, one (index) containing pointers to the location of the appropriate values in the values array. These last two parameters must be passed by reference.

```
 <?php
    $simple = '<hats>
                <a id="Chicago BULLS" img="bulls.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
                <b id="Toronto RAPTORS" img="raptors.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
                <c id="Orlando MAGIC" img="magic.jpeg" cost="$25.00" />
            </hats>
            <clothes>
                <a id="Chicago BULLS 23" img="bullstee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
                <b id="Toronto RAPTORS 23" img="torontotee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
                <c id="Orlando MAGIC 23" img="magictee.jpeg" cost="$30.00" />
            </clothes>';
    $p = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($p);
    echo "Index array\n";
    print_r($index);
    echo "\nVals array\n";
    print_r($vals);
  ?>
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/xml_parse_into_struct

Comment: Writing code which reads from the struct returned by that function ends up much like writing a custom parser using `xml_parse`; there are generally better options if you just want to access a basic XML structure.

Comment: I have given this a go and it has made an array, but I am unable to figure out how the array works let alone how to easily call on it.
I had a look at the link you posted and further down it talks about a function 'AminoAcid' as the example used, this gave a much better looking result in the array structure.
It is important how the layout of the array is because I wish to call on all items from array->hats and then to call on only items from array->clothes, if that makes sense.