# Recursive Expat XML to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, recursion, xml-parsing

I wrote a recursive function that is supposed to convert an xml into an associative array.
The function I wrote so far worked with the root element containing 1 child only, however when I tried it on an xml which the root has more than 1 child, it only outputted the first child.

Here is the function I wrote:
`$values` is the values array from `xml_parse_into_struct`.

```
    function _xml2array($append, $values, $i) {
    if($i == count($values) - 1) {
        return $append;
    }

    switch($values[$i]['type']) {
        case 'open':
            $tag = $values[$i]['tag'];
            $append[$tag][] = _xml2array($append[$tag], $values, ++$i);
            return $append;
        case 'complete':
            $tag = $values[$i]['tag'];
            $val = $values[$i]['value'];
            $append[$tag] = $val;
            return _xml2array($append, $values, ++$i);
        case 'close':
            return $append;
    }
}

function xml2array($values) {
    return _xml2array(array(), $values, 0);
}
```

And here is the xml I'm working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<espadas>
    <espada>
        <name>Coyote Starrk</name>
        <rank>Primera</rank>
        <resurreccion>
            <release-command>Kick About</release-command>
            <zan-name>Los Lobos</zan-name>
        </resurreccion>
    </espada>
    <espada>
        <name>Baraggan Louisenbairn</name>
        <rank>Segunda</rank>
        <resurreccion>
            <release-command>Rot</release-command>
            <zan-name>Arrogante</zan-name>
        </resurreccion>
    </espada>
</espadas>
```

And here is the output I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [ESPADAS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ESPADA] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [NAME] => Coyote Starrk
                                    [RANK] => Primera
                                    [RESURRECCION] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [RELEASE-COMMAND] => Kick About
                                                    [ZAN-NAME] => Los Lobos
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong that I'm only getting the first child?
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Tried debugging again, and realized I need to put a base case.
But that still leaves me with an array with the first child only.

Comment: I did not consider that, I could just drop the root element `ESPADAS` and have the root key as `ESPADA` and store each `ESPADA` in its current position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the expectation encoded that there is one child-element with the same tag-name.

```
$append[$tag] = _xml2array ...
```

This is a wrong expectation. XML can have 0-n child-element(s) with the same tag-name.

Therefore you need to encode the case, that there can be zero or more tagnames:

```
$append[$tag][] = _xml2array ...
```

As you also do the same mistake on the `complete` state, you need to modify your code there as well, which I leave as a trivial excercise to apply the given answer there, too.

Comment: The ones in complete will appear only once, so can I leave them as is? And I added the change you wrote `...[$tag][] = ...` it still only showed the first element.

Comment: I would treat all cases equal to keep complexity low. Otherwise you would need to think about each time which case you have and use different logic to deal with it. Next to that, if I may ask, what is wrong with the array that `xml_parse_into_struct` already returns?

Comment: And now as you comment it, you might also have a flaw when you pass `$append[$tag]` into `_xml2array`. I didn't highlight that part so far.

Comment: I want to show the array in a neat way, with only tag and value without other data like levels and type.

Comment: Where do you want to show it? If it's display only, you don't need to change the structure, just the way you print/display it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am currently only displaying the array to make sure its correct, but what I meant is that I will be using it to get data from xml in the array form.

Comment: You already have the data in array form by using `xml_parse_into_struct`. Sorry to state the obvious. You are perhaps solving a problem which does not exists.

Comment: The array resulting from `xml_parse_into_struct` will be a 1 dimensional array, the array I want mine to be is multidimensional array that represents a structured nested array representation of the xml.

Comment: I understand, but keep in mind that even the array you already get back from `xml_parse_into_struct` does contain the nesting information from within the XML. I think you're on the right way to come to there with the code you've started to far, you might just need a little trouble-shooting and introduce tests so that you can actually follow that your code does what you want to do. E.g. reduce the XML to the bare minimum to trigger your problem, then fix it.

Comment: And please read this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997766/converting-an-xml-into-a-php-multidimensional-array#comment29800121_19997869 - You're perhaps using the wrong tool for the job. As you load the whole XML into memory through that array, there is not much reason to use an XML parser right ahead that offers you multi-dimenstional access to the XML data already. Like `SimpleXMLElement` or `DOMDocument`. You might think the array is easier to deal with, but that's probably just causing you headaches as parsing and acessing XML is solved in PHP with ease.