# dynamically push multidimensional array in php from xml

Tags: php, xml, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array based on an xml file. the file only includes **menu,menu->link**  and **menu->submenu,menu->submenu->link**. I want an multidimensional array to be looked like this.

```
array()  
0=>menu1  
  0=>submenu1  
  1=>sublink1  
1=>link1  
2=>menu2  
  0=>submenu1  
  1=>sublink1
  2=>submenu2  
  3=>sublink2
3=>link2  
....  
....
```

the xml code is given here:

```
<page> 
  <title>Examination Remuneration</title>  

  <menu title ="Home" link="http://">  
    <submenu title="About" link="#">  
    </submenu>  
  </menu>  

  <menu title ="Data Entry" link="http://">  
    <submenu title="Form 1" link="#">  
    </submenu>  
    <submenu title="Form 2" link="#">  
    </submenu>  
  </menu>  
</page>
```

what i have tried:

```
<?php  
  $main = simplexml_load_file("MENUU.xml");  
  $allmenu = array();  
  foreach ($main->menu as $menu) {  
    array_push($allmenu,$menu["title"]);
    foreach($menu->submenu as $submenu){  
         //dont know what to do here :(
    }
    array_push($allmenu,$menu["link"]);
  }
  var_dump($allmenu);
?>
```

The problem is I cannot find how to push multi dimension and another problem is I dont know how many submenu a menu can have. Any kind of help is appreciated and TIA.

Comment: check this out: [it's been answered already here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997766/converting-an-xml-into-a-php-multidimensional-array)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php) too